# Putting a rectangle with text inside

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr, lastpage

how can I put a rectangle on the bottom page for all pages in latex and inside of each on this content 'Confidential' please?

And how can I display current page /total page ? Actually I have only the current number page displayed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{pdfstartview = {XYZ null null 1.00}} 
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% References
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancyfoot[L]{blabla}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{Confidential}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{sffamily}
  \begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
    % only works if a paragraph has started.
    \begin{figure}[th]
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/p1.png}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/m9.png}
    \end{figure}    
    \vspace{3cm}
 
  %  \textsc{\Large }\\[1.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries blabla\\[0.4cm] }
    \HRule \\[1cm]
    %\includegraphics[width=12cm]{images/f5.png}
   
   
   
    % Author and supervisor
    \Large  blabla\\
    \Large{blabla} \\
    \Large blabla\\[1cm]
    
    
\vspace{3cm}

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\ 
        \textsc{blabla}\\
        \textsc{blabla}\\
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\
        \textsc{blabla}\\
        \textsc{blabla}\\
      \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    
    % Bottom of the page
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\large 2021 - 2022}

  \end{center}
  \end{sffamily}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage

%HEADER
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[H]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/p1.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/p2.png}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
{\ \vspace{-1cm}}
\section{blabka}
blabla

\vspace{-0.5cm}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

See the following picture :[image]

Comment: Please see the updated answer using your new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It will produce a 5 page document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}% expand the header
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

% References

%\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}} % changed <<<<<<<
\fancyfoot[L]{blabla}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{CONFIDENTIAL}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\fancyfoot[R]{\leftmark}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\usepackage{lastpage}% last page <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY dummy text

\begin{document}

\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

The package `lastpage` will add a reference to the last (physical) page of your document, allowing to use `\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}`   (requires two compilations)

To add the boxed word CONFIDENTIAL use  `\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{CONFIDENTIAL}}`

**UPDATE** after follow-up question with a new code.

This code will produce a two page document plus the title page.

Main changes: (a) the header definition should be in the preamble. (b) The header height was increased. (`\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}`)

*Remove the duplicate packages !!!*

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}   

%\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}     
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}% CHANGED expand the header <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lastpage} % needed  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% References
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref} % put here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\hypersetup{pdfstartview = {XYZ null null 1.00}} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

%HEADER <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-c}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{blabla}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}  % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{Confidential}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{sffamily}
            \begin{center}
                
                % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
                % only works if a paragraph has started.
                \begin{figure}[th]
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
                \end{figure}    
                \vspace{3cm}
                %  \textsc{\Large }\\[1.5cm]                    
                % Title
                \HRule \\[0.4cm]
                { \huge \bfseries blabla\\[0.4cm] }
                \HRule \\[1cm]
                %\includegraphics[width=12cm]{images/f5.png}                
                
                % Author and supervisor
                \Large  blabla\\
                \Large{blabla} \\
                \Large blabla\\[1cm]                
                
                \vspace{3cm}
                
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \begin{flushleft} \large
                        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\ 
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                    \end{flushleft}
                \end{minipage}
                ~
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \begin{flushright} \large
                        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                    \end{flushright}
                \end{minipage}
                \vfill
                
                % Bottom of the page
                \vspace{1cm}
                {\large 2021 - 2022}
                
            \end{center}
        \end{sffamily}
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    
    \section{blabka}
    blabla
    
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not working I still have my page numbe in the center and no box for confidential. I have the pages on the right side but not the box in center, the ponly thing I've changed is not using `\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY dummy text` and putting `\kant[1-\pageref{LastPage}]`. instead of`\kant[1-20]`

Comment: cuz `\kant[1-20]` is not working

Comment: @Zokulko Copy and save my code as it is with a different name. Compile twice. Perhaps in your system you have to install the package `kantlipsum` manually.

Comment: kantlipsum I don't need this since I've already some content inside my \begin{document}

Comment: It works when I don't put content inside `\begin{document}....\end{document}`

Comment: @Zokulko It is not part of the solution. Only to make a document with several pages. Add your own content.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear sorry. The thing is that it works until I had my own content inside `\begin{document}....\end{document}`   then the flexbox goes away I don't know why ... I've updated my code if you can see please

Comment: Please why do I always get this annoying message `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.30)  22 JUL 2022 20:52 entering extended mode \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex (./main.tex LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1...` when I try to compile my doc

Comment: @Zokulko It is normal message when compiling a LaTeX document using pdflatex. The first line of the log.

Comment: I'm using overleaf, and when I compile it doesn't render at all and this message appears.... Do you think it could be the using version of my Google?

Comment: @Zokulko There is a warning `No data sources defined!` . You must consult the Overleaf support why this is happening with your code.